# Removing querystrings from the URL before page refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, caching, cookies, url-rewriting

After a new user signs up, I need to redirect the user to the home page and display a twitter-style welcome message.  I initially tried using the jquery cookie plugin to store my message and display it on the redirected page if the cookie is present, but the problem was that it didn't work across all browsers.  Firfox on Safari does not delete the cookie, so the message keeps showing everytime the browser is refreshed.  Here's the code:

```
if ($.cookie("message")) {
    TwentyQuestions.Common.ShowMessageBar($.cookie("message"), 7000);
    $.cookie('message', "any_value", { expires: -10 })
}
```

So I decided to use querystring instead, but now the problem is similar. When the home page load, the query string is detected and the message is displayed.  But how do I remove the querystring from the URL so that the message doesn't show everytime the page is refreshed?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the problem is you're trying to do everything on the client side. Instead you should set a persistent cookie associated with the user. Then in the back-end, the first time the homepage is displayed to this user, show you welcome message. Also clear whatever "first time user" flag for this user on the server side. Then the next time the user visits this page they won't see the message.

You can also do a SO like thing where if a user visits your website and the cookie doesn't exist, you can display the "Welcome first time user" message.

Comment: This will be my last resort if none of the client methods work.  @marcosfromero's solution looks like it will work for me.  Thanks...

Comment: I ended up using this method...none of the client methods were good enough to work on all browsers.

Answer (score 6):

Could you do:

```
window.location.href = window.location.href.split('?')[0];
```

It works, but I'm not for sure if this is what you are looking for?

Comment: Thanks.  This would probably work, but I don't really want to do another redirect at this point.

Comment: This works great if you have a 'clear search settings' type link or button.  Thanks Kyle

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using querystring you can use hash.

Redirect to home page with a special hash and when entering, just remove it.

Something like:

```
if(document.location.hash == '<special hash>') {
    TwentyQuestions.Common.ShowMessageBar(...);
    document.location.hash='';
}
```

Comment: This works, but the document.location.has leaves a trailing '#' behind. Only the hash word itself gets removed.  Functionally, it's fine, but is there anyway to remove it from the URL?

Comment: Don't think so. I never could.

Answer (score 0):

```
location = location.pathname + location.hash
```

This will of course lose any POST data, but if you've got a query string, they probably arrived at your site via GET anyway.

It should have no effect if the location has no query component.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with cookies but you have to delete the cookie properly. Setting an expiry date in the past works with some browsers but not others as you've found, the proper way to delete a cookie with the jQuery cookie plugin is to send in a `null`; from the [fine manual](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie/blob/master/jquery.cookie.js):

> @example $.cookie('the_cookie', null);
>   @desc Delete a cookie by passing null as value. Keep in mind that you have to use the same path and domain used when the cookie was set.

So delete it with this:

```
$.cookie('message', null);
```

and the cookie approach should work fine.

Comment: Thanks @mu.  This is what I tried first, but it doesn't seem to delete it in Chrome.